# How do I correctly query posts from a post ID?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, query-posts, get-posts

Ok so I have this code to Query posts from a certain ID:

```
    <?php 

     $valid_post_types = array ('agencies','pro-awards-winners','marcawards','topshops');


    $args = array(
       'post_type' => $valid_post_types,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'pagename' => 210639,
       'posts_per_page' => -1       
     ); 

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  // The Query
  query_posts( $args );

  //The Loop
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 echo '
 <li>';
  the_title();
 echo '</li>';
 endwhile;

// Reset Query
   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The posts aren't displaying of course...Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are a number of errors there and it would be very helpful to know exactly what you want to achieve in order to help you.  If you are trying to get a single post by ID for example, then the pagename parameter and the array of post types are irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't this your question from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233942/how-to-get-posts-from-a-sidebar-to-display-as-a-regular-posts-page ?

Comment: Hi I'm looking to get a page ID that displays those post types on it's page

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do it a different way this time

Comment: well if you already know the `pagename` why would you need the ID?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook I solved the issue by adding this: `$list_args2 = array( "post_type" => "any", "post__in" => get_post_meta( 210639, 'storylist', true), "orderby" => "post__in", 'post_status' => 'publish' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by posting adding this: 
        `$list_args2 = array( "post_type" => "any", "post__in" => get_post_meta(  210639, 'storylist', true), "orderby" => "post__in", 'post_status' => 'publish' );`

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',  //Specifying the type of posts
    'cat'=> 1,    //Selecting post category by ID to show
    'posts_per_page' => 4,  //No. of posts to show      
    'paged' => $paged       //For pagination
);
//You dont need to use query_posts( $args ); since you are using wp_query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Use while loop like this

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Instead of this

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

In case if you don't know where to find post ID, Read [this article](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/) to know about post ID

Comment: Thanks, buit I'm trying to query the posts on a specific page and not by category ID

Comment: I am little confused about your question, If you can elaborate a little more that what exactly you want to achieve then I might help you.